# ORA-00905: missing keyword for THEN clause of CASE?

Tags: mysql, oracle, postgresql, case

I have the following query:

```
SELECT name,tid FROM table_name WHERE status=1 AND
CASE
WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_name WHERE name='name1' AND tid='tid1' AND status=1)
THEN name='name1' AND tid='tid1'
ELSE name='name2' AND tid='tid2'
END;
```

The above query works for postgres and mysql but in oracle I get this error :

```
THEN name='name1' AND AND tid='tid1'
         *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00905: missing keyword
```

Can someone please tell me whats wrong here and how to correct the query to work for **all three** - postgres , mysql and oracle

Comment: it's a select query, not an update. you can't assign values to a field like that.

Comment: We are not assigning values , `name="name1" AND tid="tid1"` are part of WHERE clause. And the queries are working in mysql and postgres, only problem i am facing is in oracle

Comment: yes, you are. your `name="name1"` is not in a "decision" context, it's in the  "then", where you should be RETURNING values for the result of the case statement.

Comment: okay so does that mean oracle can handle only returning values in `then` clause and not  expressions in `then` clause

Comment: You are not alone. I asked the same question many months ago, in a different forum. Oracle SQL doesn't have a BOOLEAN data type (although, curiously, their procedural language PL/SQL does). Oracle SQL has boolean "conditions" which are used for filtering and such, but you can't "hold" boolean values. Even so, just like they wrote the code to implement CASE expressions, they could also have implemented a CASE **condition** (with very minimal extra work, I think). For whatever reason they chose not to do so.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, a `CASE` statement cannot return a boolean expression.  Here is one way to do what you want without a `CASE`:

```
SELECT name, tid
FROM table_name
WHERE status = 1 AND
      (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_name WHERE name = 'name1' AND tid = 'tid1' AND status = 1) AND
       name = 'name1' AND tid = 'tid1'
      ) OR 
      (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_name WHERE name = 'name1' AND tid = 'tid1' AND status = 1) AND
       name = 'name2' AND tid = 'tid2'
      );
```

Or, you could express this as:

```
SELECT name, tid
FROM table_name
WHERE status = 1 AND
      (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_name WHERE name = 'name1' AND tid = 'tid1' AND status = 1) 
            THEN (CASE WHEN name = 'name1' AND tid = 'tid1' THEN 'true' END)
            ELSE (CASE WHEN name = 'name2' AND tid = 'tid2' THEN 'true' END)
      ) = 'true'
```

Understanding `CASE` with booleans can be tricky.  This is even more true with nested `CASE` statements.  However, this version does have the advantage of only running the subquery once.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you can't use a CASE expression to 'add' clauses to a WHERE clause. If I understand what you're trying to do correctly it looks to me like your query can be simplified to

```
SELECT name, tid
  FROM table_name
  WHERE STATUS = 1 AND 
        ((NAME = 'name1' AND
          TID = 'tid1') OR
         (NAME = 'name2' AND
          TID = 'tid2'))
```

Best of luck.

Comment: What about the is exists condition , I want to use ` name = ''name1" and tid="tdi1" ` only if a record exist with those condition otherwise  i want to use `name= 'name2' AND
          tid = 'tid2'`

Comment: Well, you're fetching data from TABLE_NAME, and the EXISTS check is done against TABLE_NAME. That seems, to me at least, to be redundant - if the data doesn't exist it won't be fetched, and thus I don't think the EXISTS check is needed at all. Unless the TABLE_NAME in the SELECT was meant to be different than the TABLE_NAME in the EXISTS.  ???

Comment: My requirement is such that if record doesnt exist for `name= 'name1' AND tid = 'tid1' ` then i need to fallback to fetch a record with  `name= 'name2' AND tid = 'tid2'` in a single query(this all within the same table)